php KV grid float-header on top with responsive=true
I am using PHP YII KVgrid . I want to scroll table horizontally and also want the table header stick to the top when body is scrolling how to achieve this
I want to scroll table horizontally and also want the table header stick to the top when body is scrolling how to achieve this.
<?= $gridView = GridView::widget([
                        // 'containerOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-grid-wrapper'],
                        "id" => "product_listing",
                        'options' => ['class' => 'custom-polaris-grid grid-view  hidescrollbar custom_gridscroller'],
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'emptyText' => '<div class="empty-grid-options"></div>',
                        'floatHeader'=>true,
                        'floatHeaderOptions'=>['scrollingTop'=>'142'],
                        'headerContainer' => ['class' => 'kv-table-header', 'style' => 'z-index: 11'],
                        'responsive' => true,
                        'floatOverflowContainer' => true,                        
                        'pageSizeSelector' => '#pager-pagesize',
                        'mainFilterParamIndex' => 'EtsyProductsSearch',
                        'pjax' => false,
                        'striped' => false,
                        'hover' => true,
                        'panelTemplate' => '<div></div>',
                        'panelFooterTemplate' => '<div></div>',
                        'panel' => [
                            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
                            'heading' => $bulkAction,
                            'footer' => true,
                            'after' => false,
                            'before' => false
                        ],
                        'columns' => $gridColumn
                    ]); ?>

